# Retrieving input value from Tkinter sliders, which were created in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, slider, customtkinter

Hi fellow Tkinter enthusiasts. I'm creating an interface for research purposes. I would like to build an window which displays several slider questions. I was able to create these dynamically with the following code.

The problem I now run into is that each slider object has the same name, and therefor it is not possible to use the SliderQ.get() function. I tried naming each of the sliders after the elements in the dictionary (Q_1 , Q_2 etc) , but unsuccessfully.

How can I retrieve the values of each slider and save them for example in a list, or in the dictionary.

```
from tkinter import *
from customtkinter import *

root = CTk()
root.geometry("400x500")

SlideAsk     = {"Q_1":"This is my question 1.", 
    "Q_2":"This is my question 2.",
    "Q_3":"This is my question 3.",
    "Q_4":"This is my question 4."}

startrow = 0
startcol = 1


def CreateSlider(SlideAsk):
    global startrow,startcol

    for q in SlideAsk:
        label_Question = CTkLabel(master=root,text= SlideAsk[q])
        label_Question.grid(row=startrow, column=0, columnspan=1, pady=10, padx=10, sticky="w")
        startrow+=1

        SliderQ = CTkSlider(master=root,from_=1,to=5,number_of_steps=4)
        SliderQ.grid(row=startrow, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")
        startrow+=1

CreateSlider(SlideAsk)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use Python classes, as it will be easier to manipulate GUI elements.

As for your problem, putting sliders in a list (while in a for loop) will allow you to use them later:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk


SlideAsk     = {"Q_1":"This is my question 1.", 
    "Q_2":"This is my question 2.",
    "Q_3":"This is my question 3.",
    "Q_4":"This is my question 4."}


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_geometry("400x500")

        # button to show sliders values
        self.del_button = tk.Button(self, text="display", command=self.display_sliders)
        self.del_button.grid(row=0,column=3)

        # label to show sliders values
        self.status_text=tk.StringVar(self)
        self.status = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.status_text)
        self.status.grid(row=1,column=3)

        # sliders
        self.sliders_list=[]
        startrow = 0
        startcol = 1
        simple_cpt = 0
        for q in SlideAsk:
            label_Question = tk.Label(text= SlideAsk[q])
            label_Question.grid(row=startrow, column=0, columnspan=1, pady=10, padx=10, sticky="w")
            startrow+=1

            self.sliders_list.append(tk.Scale(self, from_=1,to=5))
            self.sliders_list[simple_cpt].grid(row=startrow, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")
            simple_cpt += 1
            startrow+=1

    def display_sliders(self):
        text=""
        for i in range(len(self.sliders_list)):
            text+=list(SlideAsk.keys())[i] + " : " + str(self.sliders_list[i].get()) + " | "
        self.status_text.set(text)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

The list containing the sliders is **sliders_list**, it is used when clicking on the button display. For each slider in the list we get its value, and display it in the label.

Comment: Thanks for your clear solution and constructive suggestions! It works perfectly.